How to use an SSH key inside a build (Kaniko) in GitLab CI?
Please help. I'm trying to install composer dependencies in build_fpm, namely private modules (repositories).
I need composer to find the key for SSH authorization.
Here is my gitlab-ci.yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_template: &build_template
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.6.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  cache:
    key: ${CI_PROJECT_PATH}
    paths:
      - /kaniko/.docker
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(echo -n "json_key:${CI_REGISTRY_KEY}" | base64 | tr -d '\n' )\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}-${TARGET}"
      --target ${TARGET}
      --cache=true
      --cache-repo="${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}/cache"
      --cache-ttl=24h

build_fpm:
  <<: *build_template
  stage: build
  variables:
    TARGET: fpm_server

build_webserver:
  <<: *build_template
  stage: build
  variables:
    TARGET: web_server
  needs:
    - build_fpm

build_cli:
  <<: *build_template
  stage: build
  variables:
    TARGET: cli
  needs:
    - build_fpm

build_cron:
  <<: *build_template
  stage: build
  variables:
    TARGET: cron
  needs:
    - build_fpm


I will be very grateful for any hint!
I did everything as in the GitLab documentation
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ssh_keys.html
if you use a separate build, then everything works correctly
setup_ssh:
  stage: build
  image: ubuntu:latest
  script:
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ls -la ~/.ssh
    - ssh -vT git@gitlab.com


It depends on how Kaniko Executor works with --build-arg option, which I have no idea about. Did you try setting up the ~/.ssh folder like in setup_ssh job, at the beginning of your build_template job?

yes, but it didn’t work out that way. To install, you need the openssh package, but in kaniko this cannot be done through the package installer.

I solved this problem differently. I created two variables in the project settings - SSH_PUBLIC_KEY and SSH_PRIVATE_KEY, created an rsa key and passed it to these variables. The key is tied to a special service account. After which I passed these variables to kaniko and declared the keys in the Dockerfile for a specially created composer user. Everything worked! Not sure if this is the right decision

Good to hear that you resolved it. You might wanna post the solution as an answer to your question. It will then help future readers eventually.
